# Merge 2 rows into one row

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query :

```
Select ID, Groucode
from mytable
```

which returns this result:

```
ID  GroupCode
---------------
60  00        
60  01         
70  00         
80  00
80  01
90  00
```

What I want is to shows only the rows with '00' and '01', like this:

```
ID   GroupCode
---------------
60    00  
60    01    
80    00
80    01
```

Comment: Select ID , GroupCode 
from mytable where GroupCode in (00,01)

Answer (score 4):

We can use aggregation here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID
    FROM mytable
    WHERE GroupCode IN ('00', '01')
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GroupCode) = 2
)

SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM cte);
```

### Demo

Note that if the `GroupCode` column is really numeric, then displaying your data as `00` and `01` is not reflective of the underlying data, because SQL Server will really just treat those values as 0 and 1.  In that case, you may modify my above query slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I am a fresher to SQL Server , Please find my answer for above mentioned concept  and you can make me correct if i am wrong .

```
Select mytable.* from mytable
inner join
(select   id  from mytable   group by id  having  count(id)>1) as table2 on mytable.id = table2.id
```